# Cambiar el toolset de mi proyecto en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Como puedo cambiar el toolset de mi proyecto para que se pueda compilar usando la versión 12.0. En mi caso mi proyecto utiliza la versión 14.0. Cuando intento compilarlo me devuelve el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma o manera de hacerlo compatible con la versión 12.0 mía de `Visual Studio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres cambiar el toolset de tu proyecto tienes que modificar el archivo `.vcxproj`

Cambiar `<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0"` por `<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0"`.

Y en todas las apariciones de `<PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>` por `<PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar cambiar el Platform Toolset haciendo click derecho sobre el icono de tu projecto en el Explorador de soluciones(Solution Explorer) y buscar la propiedad PlatformToolset.

En el peor de los casos tendras que instalar **Visual Studio 2015**.

Te dejo un link con mas instrucciones mas detalladas de como realizar el cambio.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ff770576.aspx